Why is the product measure not defined on the Caratheodory sigma-algebra?
Let $(X, \mathscr{M}, \mu)$ and $(Y, \mathscr{N}, \nu)$ be measure spaces. The product measure $\mu \times \nu$ is usually defined on the product $\sigma$-algebra $\mathscr{M} \otimes \mathscr{N}$. Why is this taken to be the domain, rather than the Carathéodory-measurable sets?
Let me be a little more explicit. Since we're working with a product of two spaces, $\mathscr{M} \otimes \mathscr{N}$ is generated by the "rectangles" $\{A \times B : A \in \mathscr{M}, B \in \mathscr{N}\}$.  The collection $\mathscr{A}$ of finite disjoint unions of rectangles forms an algebra, and we define a pre-measure on this algebra by
$(\mu \times \nu)_0(E) = \sum_{j = 1}^n \mu(A_j)\nu(B_j)$ whenever $E = (A_1 \times B_1) \sqcup \ldots \sqcup (A_n \times B_n)$.
This pre-measure induces an outer measure $(\mu \times \nu)^*$, and we define the product measure to be the restriction of this outer measure to the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\mathscr{A}$---which coincides with $\mathscr{M} \otimes \mathscr{N}$.
Question. Why do we not proceed as with the construction of complete measures, and instead restrict the outer measure $(\mu \times \nu)^*$ to the $\sigma$-algebra of sets satisfying Carathéodory's criterion?
What issues would arise if we defined the product measure in this way?
For reference, I'm reading Folland's Real Analysis.

Product sigma-algebras are intrinsic to the measurable spaces, and that this approach identifies the product measure as defined on a sigma-algebra determined only by the underlying measurable spaces, not the measures they are equipped with.

The product sigma algebra is the smallest sigma-algebra which contains all measurable rectangles, or, equivalently, the smallest sigma-algebra on the product space under which the coordinate mappings $(x,y)\to x$, $(x,y)\to y$, are measurable.

A very important particular case is of Borel sigma algebras. Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are topological spaces, and let's consider the Borel sigma algebras on each and the product, ${\cal B}(X),{\cal B}(Y)$ and ${\cal B}(X\times Y)$. By construction, the product topology is the smallest topology under which the above mappings are both continuous. Going back to measure theory, and considering the Borel sigma-algebras ${\cal B}(X),{\cal B}(Y)$ and ${\cal B}(X\times Y)$,  it follows from the definitions that ${\cal B}(X\times Y) = {\cal B}(X)\times {\cal B}(Y)$.


In light of the above, it is natural to extend a measure on ${\cal M}$ and a measure on ${\cal N}$ to a measure on the product. That measure can be later completed, but the completion will be defined on a sigma algebra which depends on the underlying measures, not a notion intrinsic to the measurable spaces.
Think of the most natural way to define the Lebesgue measure in ${\mathbb R}^n$: defined on open cubes, equal to $1$ on the unit cube,  translation invariant, $n$-homogeneous, complete. All but last imply that the sigma-algebra must contain ${\cal B}({\mathbb R}^n)$. These conditions easily  imply that its restriction to ${\cal B}({\mathbb R}^n)$ coincides with the $n$-fold product of the restriction of the Lebesgue measure to ${\cal B}({\mathbb R})$, and so, the Lebesgue measure is exactly the completion of this product.

Two remarks: $\mathcal{B}(X \times Y) = \mathcal{B}(X) \otimes \mathcal{B}(Y)$ needs $X$ and $Y$ to be second-countable. And if one completes the measure defined on the product $\sigma$-measure, then the $\sigma$-algebra on which the extended measure is defined is actually exactly the $\sigma$-algebra of Carathéodory-measurable sets w.r.t. the outer measure the OP mentioned (equivalently, the outer measure obtained from the product measure). (I guess technically we should assume all measures involved are $\sigma$-finite, as otherwise the definition of product measure is a bit problematic.)

Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for. I'm guessing that there are situations where one might wish to study the behaviour of a collection of product measures (defined by corresponding collections of measures on the component measurable spaces), but to compare the product measures one would need them to be defined on a common domain? Do you know of any situations where something like this might arise?

Here is an example. I hope it makes some sense.  Suppose both are probability measures. Take $Z_1$ as a random variable on the first and $Z_2$ a random variable on the second. Then $(Z_1,Z_2)$ and compositions of it with Borel functions from ${\mathbb R}^2$ to itself (e.g. $(Z_2,-Z_1), (Z_2e^{Z_1+Z_2},1/(1+Z_1^2))$, etc...) are all random vectors on the product space. The distribution of each of those is always described as a probability measure on ${\cal B}({\mathbb R}^2)$.

The tensor product of two measures is a more primitive construction. Its completion gives another measure. For the Lebesgue measure, $\mathcal{L}^2 = (\mathcal{L}\otimes\mathcal{L})^*$.
